# Ansible CSV lookup in Jinja2 template, how to handle missing key

Tags: python, csv, ansible, jinja2

j2 template and here is a snippet:

```
{% set denyGroups %}
{{lookup('csvfile', '{{ ansible_hostname }} file={{ csvFile }} delimiter=, col=5')}}
{% endset %}
{%- if denyGroups |trim() -%}
simple_deny_groups = {{ denyGroups |replace(";", ",") }}
{%- endif -%}
```

I am injecting values into the template based on csv values. However, if the key (ansible_hostname ) is not found in the csv, get this error: `AnsibleError: csvfile: list index out of range`

How can I do this error handling? Check if its in the csv first. Now I could inject the value in tasks, but that will be a bit more cumbersome, and I prefer this template way. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`list index out of range` – it's a problem with number of columns.
Columns are counted from zero, so for `col=5` – there must be 6 columns in the file.
If you want to return a default item if key is missing, use `default=myvalue` option.

Update: Let's look into [the code](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/devel/lib/ansible/plugins/lookup/csvfile.py#L59):

```
def read_csv(self, filename, key, delimiter, encoding='utf-8', dflt=None, col=1):

    try:
        f = open(filename, 'r')
        creader = CSVReader(f, delimiter=to_bytes(delimiter), encoding=encoding)

        for row in creader:
            if row[0] == key:
                return row[int(col)]
    except Exception as e:
        raise AnsibleError("csvfile: %s" % to_str(e))

    return dflt
```

So in the csv like this:

```
mykey,val_a,val_b.val_c
```

key (column 0) is mykey, column 1 - val_a, column 2 - val_b, column 3 - val_c.

**If there is a format error or your parameters are incorrect, exception will be triggered – you can't do anything about it.** Trying to use `col=4` with my example csv file will rise `list index out of range` exception.

If the key is not found in the file (`row[0] == key` was false for every line), default value will be returned (the one you specify with `default=` option).

Comment: I tried using the default argument, but it gave me the same result.

Comment: The documentation contradicts itself a bit. "The first value in the argument is the key, which must be an entry that appears exactly once in column 0". Notice: must be an entry that appears exactly once. Then default empty string Default return value if the key is not in the csv file. But it does say with this argument the default value is an empty string, so it should not be failing.

Comment: @Codemiester I've updated my answer with code snippet and some comments.

Comment: It is very strange. I looked at the code and it makes sense. But I am still getting the same error. All I did was remove the line in the csv. When its present and the lookup should work, it does, but when removed it doesnt.

Comment: Found the problem, there was a blank line in the csv, that was after the row I was looking for. Thanks for your help.